# Custom Exception Handling in ANTLR4, C#?

Tags: c#, antlr4

Java examples of custom error-handling in C# for ANTLR4 do not translate one-to-one to C#, I've found.  After receiving multiple downvotes on my question, I'm trying again.

I need to make a custom error handler using the C# bindings that stops on ANY syntax or lexical error.

Java examples suggest

```
public static class BailSimpleLexer extends SimpleLexer { ...
```

But there is no SimpleLexer object in the C# binding.  I cannot find an example that is similar to available Java examples, so I'm curious how other C# ANTLR4 developers have solved the problem of trapping all lexical errors, like TestRig does.

Answer (score 0):

The lexer I needed to create is inherited from the base lexer created by ANTLR4:

```
public class BailLexer : LISBASICLexer
{
    public BailLexer(ICharStream input) : base(input) { }
    public override void Recover(LexerNoViableAltException e)
    {
        throw new ParseCanceledException(e);
    }
}
```